# How to set element height for a fixed number of lines of text

Tags: css

Given some text that occupies about 10 rows, how can I resize its container to only show the first 3 rows and hide the others? Apparently this works, but I think it is not reliable:

```
.container {
    height: 7.5ex; /* 2.5ex for each visible line */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Can I rely on the fact that `height of one row = 2.5ex` or is that just a coincidence in the browsers I am using to test?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you are going to use this you should ensure the `line-height` is always 2.5ex

```
.container {
  line-height: 2.5ex;
  height: 7.5ex; /* 2.5ex for each visible line */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vsgsN/)

Comment: Just in case someone is wondering what is `ex` unit: [What is the value of the css 'ex' unit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918612/what-is-the-value-of-the-css-ex-unit)

Comment: Great Job!! Solved!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the webkit property line-clamp

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

It doesn't work on all browsers, but hopefully it will one day.

Comment: how can I use this inside a flex div with 2 items? let's say an svg icon + a 2 line clamp div in a row flex div. thanks!

Comment: This was the right solution for me and the feature now works on all major browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Use `rem`:

```
.container {
    height: 3rem; /* 1rem for each visible line */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set the line height of a text and with it knows the exact height of each row and set desired height of your container, simply doing this:

```
.container {
    line-height:25px;
    height:75px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Now everything works rightly :)