# Why use something like "width: 22ex" in CSS?

Tags: css

When reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918612/) question, i was wondering why anybody uses ex as a measurement for the **width** of an element. I understand that ex represents the **height** of a lowercase x, so i can use it to define the height of a input-box - for example.

But why would anybody use ex for the width of this box? Isn't that possibly wrong depending on the type? And why shouldn't I just use em in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height and width of elements are usually best specified considering both at the same time, to achieve "pleasing" ratios (e.g. 16:9, or the golden ratio). So just because `ex` is specified in terms of a height, it doesn't make it less useful for specifying a particular width.

And you shouldn't use `em` instead, since it's the width of the upper case M. It's highly unlikely that the two measurements are the same.

---

As a corollary, you'll find plenty of example layouts that specify heights in terms on `em`s, which is again because they're considering the ratios between heights and widths.

Comment: I am not completely happy with the answer. Of course, if I want the height in relation to the width it would make sense, but I highly doubt that if you want to specify the width of an input-box you are going for "pleasing" ratios. Do you see any reason why anybody should use it in this case?

Comment: @Tobo - I agree it's odd if it's the only use of `ex` in the entire (set of) stylesheet(s), but if the entire layout is being constructed in terms of `ex`, then no, I don't think it's odd. (Added to which, assuming a non-fixed-width font, using any font-metric to set the width of the box can't be to limit the number of characters displayed)

Comment: em is defined as the the *height* of an upper-case M, not the width.

Answer (score 0):

Since ex refers to height, rather than width, using it to set a width seems to be simply an error, imho. You should just use em to make the width relative to the text's width.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Both em and ex refers to height. em is the height of an upper-case M, ex is the height of a lower-case x.

Answer (score -1):

What @Andrei Bârsan said and, further, because few characters are as wide as 'em', you can use 'en' as a width specifier. 'en' will give you the width of any digit.