# Remove space added by line break in HTML code (with CSS?)

Tags: html, css

I have some html that looks like this:

```
<span>
  398
  <span>comments posted in</span>
</span>
```

A space is rendered after `398` because there is a line-break in the html.  For reasons I won't go into, this line-break cannot be removed.  Is there a way to stop a space being rendered there?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @cimmanon Good one! `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It is not possible using CSS. Although you can use `float`, but it doesn't work out here.

But I have a crappy idea, give this CSS (Ideal Case):

```
span span {margin-left: -1em;}
span span {margin-left: -1ex;}
```

But the practical case was like this:

```
span span {margin-left: -0.4em;}
span span {margin-left: -0.7ex;}
```

`1em` or `1ex` is the width of a space character in CSS. Hope it works! Everyone knows about `em`. So something about `ex`:

> The ‘ex’ unit is defined by the font’s ‘x-height’. The x-height is so called because it is often equal to the height of the lowercase "x". However, an ‘ex’ is defined even for fonts that don’t contain an "x".

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UmdfA/

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Well, @NickBrunt Still I don't get you what you said. So, you knew this before, but needed something better, or you needed this?

Comment: @NickBrunt I used a `0.4em` in my fiddle. You need to tweak it according to the font and size you use. `:)`

Comment: I had an inkling that it wasn't possible, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Yes, it does work, but it doesn't actually remove the space character, which would have been ideal.  Thanks anyway though :)

Comment: I recommend using `ex` units as `1em` will be more than a space in most typefaces. The `ex` unit is the height of an `x`, which is more likely to match the width of a space.

Comment: I disagree with @SteveFenton. Opening [his fiddle that uses ex](http://jsfiddle.net/pcsU7/) in Firefox 16, I see the number and letters overlapping.

Comment: @ANeves Anyway, it needs to be calibrated. I have given **practical** vs **ideal** CSS.

Answer (score 3):

I think we are all agreed that the correct solution *where possible* is this:

```
<span>
  398<span>comments posted in</span>
</span>
```

But you could use some CSS shenanigans to sort this out...

```
span span {
    margin-left: -1ex;
}
```

Or

```
span span {
    position: relative;
    left: -1ex;
}
```

Comment: Yes, clearly putting it on the same line is ideal, I don't like having to hack it but margins seem like the only solution in my situation.

Comment: -1: [`ex` is for height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918612/what-is-the-value-of-the-css-ex-unit), using it for width is a bad idea. The number and the text overlap for me, in that Fiddle. (Firefox 16.)

Comment: Ugh, the spec goes on about [`em squares`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-size), which indicates that em can be for width as well as for height... which I guess means ex can be for both too. Also, *"[according to Mozilla](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Em_vs._ex) Gecko can scale items using exes a bit more accurately than those using ems"* ([via](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918612/what-is-the-value-of-the-css-ex-unit#comment9316381_918623)) I want to undo the -1 :(

Comment: Ha! Don't worry about it :). The unit of ex is based on the height of an x but can be used to define a width. 1ex means "make this as wide as an x is high".