# How to set max-height of text equal to line number

Tags: html, css, text, units-of-measurement

I have text, which is changed dynamically and I want to prevent it to be more than 3 lines for example (taking into account `font-size` and `line-height` properties).

**Is it possible to achieve that in css only?**

The use case is that I am using an external library, which sets the line-height of font, so I cannot calculate it dynamically in css.

Also I have tried `3em`, `6ex`, `4.5ch`, after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918612/what-is-the-value-of-the-css-ex-unit), and it did not work for me, because it does not take into account the `line-height` property.

Example http://joxi.ru/48AnKxpiNXJgrO

Comment: Yes you can do that with css using multiple line ellipsis. Take a look at [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpeeEP) example.

Comment: Thanks! It looks very persuasively, but it seems to be non [cross-browser](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/), is there any other possibilities?

Comment: I think its pretty cross-browser. I checked it on firefox, chrome and internet explorer.

Comment: @wazaaaap Doesn't this only work because you set the line height yourself? I thought the OP couldn't do that.

Comment: @mr-lister exactly, only because of height it works in FF :( There should be some values, as `ex` or `ch`, which can be used.